# How to ensure thread safe ASP.net page to access static list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, synchronization, thread-safety

In my web application i am having following common objectList for all online users.

```
public static List<MyClass> myObjectList = new List<MyClass>();
```

so when multiple online users try to **read** data from this object **myObjectList** then are there any chances of **thread synchronization issue**.

In another scenario multiple users are reading from **myObjectList** and few of them are writing also but every user is writing on a different **index** of List . Every user may add a new item to this list . So now I think there are chances of **synchronization issue**.

How to write thread safe utility class that can read and write data from this object in safer way.

Suggestions are highly welcome

Code suggested by Angelo looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ObjectPoolExample
{
    public class ObjectPool<T>
    {
        private ConcurrentBag<T> _objects;
        private Func<T> _objectGenerator;

        public ObjectPool(Func<T> objectGenerator)
        {
            if (objectGenerator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("objectGenerator");
            _objects = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
            _objectGenerator = objectGenerator;
        }

        public T GetObject()
        {
            T item;
            if (_objects.TryTake(out item)) return item;
            return _objectGenerator();
        }

        public void PutObject(T item)
        {
            _objects.Add(item);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // Create an opportunity for the user to cancel.
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c' || Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'C')
                        cts.Cancel();
                });

            ObjectPool<MyClass> pool = new ObjectPool<MyClass> (() => new MyClass());            

            // Create a high demand for MyClass objects.
            Parallel.For(0, 1000000, (i, loopState) =>
                {
                    MyClass mc = pool.GetObject();
                    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                    // This is the bottleneck in our application. All threads in this loop
                    // must serialize their access to the static Console class.
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:####.####}", mc.GetValue(i));                 

                    pool.PutObject(mc);
                    if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        loopState.Stop();                 

                });
            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    // A toy class that requires some resources to create.
    // You can experiment here to measure the performance of the
    // object pool vs. ordinary instantiation.
    class MyClass
    {
        public int[] Nums {get; set;}
        public double GetValue(long i)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(Nums[i]);
        }
        public MyClass()
        {
            Nums = new int[1000000];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < Nums.Length; i++)
                Nums[i] = rand.Next();
        }
    }   
}
```

I think i can go with this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you are better off changing to one of the [thread-safe collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx) already supported by the runtime, like for example a [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx).

The concurrent bag however does not support access by index if I recall correctly so you may need to resort to a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) if you need access to an object by a given key.

If .NET 4.0 is not an option you should read the following blog post:

[Why are thread safe collections so hard?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/11/why-are-thread-safe-collections-so-hard.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link I m using 4.0

Comment: Angelo can u please tell by having a look at updated question text ,that doing this way will be safe and efficient or not.

Comment: Using the `ConcurrentBag` will make it safe, the efficient part will need to be judged by you according to the performance requirements you have.

Comment: thanks a lot . I am going to use this approach to render same set of Quiz Questions to various person giving quiz online , when a student of another course logged in to give quiz then new set of questions get added to this list<MyClass> specific to his course and all subsequent students can get data from the same index.